# Getting a cross origin error when running my Cypress tests in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, cross-domain, subdomain, cypress

I'm running my Cypress locally and they are always pass, but when I'm running them in jenkins, I keep getting this error:

```
  > Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Before the page load, you were bound to the origin policy:
  > http://localhost:3000

A cross origin error happens when your application navigates to a new superdomain which does not match the origin policy above.

This typically happens in one of three ways:

1. You clicked an <a> that routed you outside of your application
2. You submitted a form and your server redirected you outside of your application
3. You used a javascript redirect to a page outside of your application

Cypress does not allow you to change superdomains within a single test.

You may need to restructure some of your test code to avoid this problem.

Alternatively you can also disable Chrome Web Security which will turn off this restriction by setting { chromeWebSecurity: false } in your 'cypress.json' file.

https://on.cypress.io/cross-origin-violation
```

sometimes one of them passes
I tried to add `chromeWebSecurity: false` to my cypress.json
but got "data:" in my url after logging in the test
(I'm logging out w/ api call that doesn't do a redirect)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress throwing SecurityError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046632/cypress-throwing-securityerror)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is some javascript that is calling `window.top.location` or some other form of redirect. We call this `framebusting`, when your app *busts out* of its `iframe` into the cypress top level frame. Cypress attempts to strip out this `framebusting` code via  a `regex` but it's possible for code to slip through.

You should either:

- find and disable/remove the `framebusting` javascript
- submit an issue with more specifics to the cypress team here

here's some similar issues to yours: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc+framebust