# Cypress throwing SecurityError

Tags: google-chrome, cypress

I am currently running with Chrome 74 and trying to use Cypress to test a style-guide in my app. When I load up Cypress it throws this error:

> SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000"
> from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Please let me know if there is a solution to this!

I had tried to follow along with this:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1951

But nothing has changed/worked for me. :(

My code is shown below: `cypress/plugins/index.js`

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, args) => {
        // browser will look something like this
        // {
        //   name: 'chrome',
        //   displayName: 'Chrome',
        //   version: '63.0.3239.108',
        //   path: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
        //   majorVersion: '63'
        // }

        if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
            args.push('--disable-site-isolation-trials');

            return args
        }

        if (browser.name === 'electron') {
            args['fullscreen'] = true

            // whatever you return here becomes the new args
            return args
        }
    })
}
```

in my `cypress/support/index.js`

This will load the site before every test I run to save myself from having to write cy.visit in every test.

```
beforeEach(() =>{
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/style-guide')
})
```

Answer (score 57):

I had the very same issue yesterday and the answer from *@jsjoeio* in the cypress [issue #1951](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1951) you've referenced in your question actually helped me.

So basically only thing I've done was to modify my `cypress.json` and add following value:

```
{
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can disable security to overcome this issue.

1. Go to `cypress.config.js` file.
2. Add this line: `chromeWebSecurity: false` and save. For example:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  ...,
  chromeWebSecurity: false // add this line
})
```

3. Run the test again.

Comment: even after pasting that into my cypress.config.js I'm facing the same issue.

This is my cypress.config.js

const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  },
});

Comment: this will throw access denied to some unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem, I advise you to do as DurkoMatko recommends. [Documentation chromeWebSecurity](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Limitations)

But I encountered another problem with a link pointing to localhost in an iframe.
If you want to use a link in an iframe I recommend this :

```js
cy.get('iframe').then((iframe) => {
  const body = iframe.contents().find('body');
  cy.wrap(body).find('a').click();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

So, at least for me, my further problem was an internal one with tokens, logins, etc. BUT!

the code I posted for how the index in the plugin folder is correct to bypass the chrome issue. That is how you want to fix it!

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced this issue. My application was using service workers. Disabling service workers while visiting a page solved the issue.

```
cy.visit('index.html', {
  onBeforeLoad (win) {
    delete win.navigator.__proto__.serviceWorker
  }
})
```

Ref: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-tips-and-tricks/#disable-serviceworker

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto your cypress.json file.
2. Set chrome web security as false

   ```
   {
       "chromeWebSecurity": false
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> To get around these restrictions, Cypress implements some strategies involving JavaScript code, the browser's internal APIs, and network proxying to play by the rules of same-origin policy.

1. Acess your project
2. In file 'cypress.json' insert

```js
{
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

Reference: [Cypress Documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Set-chromeWebSecurity-to-false)