# Cypress can't navigate to a specific Email Service (Proton Mail)

Tags: cypress

[image: Proton Mail]

I'm new to Cypress and i encountered this problem, basically what i need to do is just login and do some testing in the site.

Link: [Proton Mail](https://account.proton.me/login)

The first error when visiting the site was a Security Error:

`Blocked a frame with origin "http://..." from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

[Cypress Throwing Security Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046632/cypress-throwing-securityerror)

So i did what the suggested solution was, now the Security Error was gone but the page doesn't seem to load after adding it in the `cypress.config`

I'm kinda confused how to solve this problem is it because of the site? or i need other tweaks to solve this issue?

The test is very simple:

```
it('should navigate to Protonmail', () => {
   cy.visit('https://account.proton.me/login')
   login_proton(Cypress.env('test').email, Cypress.env('test').password)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that there's no workaround for this https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7449

I suggest to change email service you're using, in my case testing framework, i switched to Playwright.